# A value of type 'Object' can't be returned from the method '_onBackPressed' because it has a return type of 'Future<bool>'. after updating the SDK

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a pop-up that asks whether to exit the application or not, it worked correctly. But after updating the SDK version, an error occurred:
"A value of type 'Object' can't be returned from the method '_onBackPressed' because it has a return type of 'Future'"
I will be grateful for your help
My code:

```html
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('You want to exit the application?'),
        content: new Text('You want to exit the application',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child:
            Text("No",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: Text("Yes",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ??
        false;
  }
```

Image with errore:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, and `showDialog` returns Future.

```dart
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
    return await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) =>
```